# no such table: myAppName_user

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model (in app with name:`services`) defined for extend the `auth.User`, it likes:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Order(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I also tried:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

then I visit the Admin page, click the `Order`, always the error:

```
OperationalError 
Exception Value:
no such table: services_user
```

I tried everything of `manage.py syncdb`, `manage.py makemigrations`, `manage.py migrate`, all not help.

seems the Django still trying to find the customized user table, this is my setting file, and it's almost the default one in Django1.8.3 without changes:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'services',
)
```

BTW: what's is the best way to empty the database? delete the sqlite file, then where to restore a empty db file?         or connect to db by `sqlshell` and drop tables one by one?

Comment: what is your AUTH_USER_MODEL setting ?

Comment: Just guessing, your admin says `no such table: services_user`, do you happen to have a model `User` defined in your app `services` as well? Table names in database are created by using `<app-name>_<model-name>`.

Comment: @RajeshKaushik I didn't have that settings, is that necessary?

Comment: @ShangWang I used to have a model of `User` in this app, and it was removed(by delete the definition in models.py) since I feel it's better to use the existed one in `django.contrib.auth`, so that's why i come out the question of how to initialize database once I have some major database tables' schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the database. This can be done by deleting the sqlite db file. Then again create empty database. For creating database first install command line tool

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

For example, to create a new SQLite database named "ex1" with a single table named "tbl1", you might do this:

```
$ sqlite3 ex1
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-05-29 12:36:14
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table tbl1(one varchar(10), two smallint);
sqlite> insert into tbl1 values('hello!',10);
sqlite> insert into tbl1 values('goodbye', 20);
sqlite> select * from tbl1;
hello!|10
goodbye|20
sqlite>
```

For details please read [this](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html).

Also you need to clear all your migrations and then again use

```
Python manage.py makemigrations

Python manage.py migrate
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: but how to create a empty database file?